# Swagger UI POST don't get any body request

Tags: api, post, swagger

i'm trying to have a POST for my API documentation, but i don't get any body request to show up in my page with this code and schema used, can someone help ? it works OK with the GET

```
    /api/v1/users:
      post:
       summary: Add a new User

       requestBody:
         description: Optional description in *Markdown*
         required: true
         content:
           application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/User"
      responses:
        200:
          description: A list of users.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/User"

        500:
          description: Internal Server Error
          schema:
            type: string
            example: "Internal Server Error"
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Is your API definition `openapi: 3.x.x` or `swagger: '2.0'`? Your example uses a mix of 3.0 abd 2.0 syntax, that's probably why it doesn't work. Also, the indentation of `responses` looks off. Paster your full spec into https://editor.swagger.io and fix any errors it reports.